# Regex - Complex Capture

Tags: regex, vb.net

This is hard to explain, I have this Regex `([a-zA-Z][\w.]+|[0-9][0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w.]*):(.*)` - It captures `Username:Whatever` and it only captures usernames on the First Capture Group.

The issue is that when I replace the Username part with an Email, It captures everything after the @ of the email. I want it to capture NOTHING at all not even the "Whatever" bit.

I cant find a way to do this.

Example input's:

```
username@domain.ext:123abc
username:123abc
shiny@gmail.com:abc123
Shiny:abc123
```

Output should be:

```
username:123abc
Shiny:abc123
```

Current Regex outputs:

```
domain.ext:123abc
username:123abc
gmail.com:abc123
shiny:abc123
```

Comment: Use anchors: `^([a-zA-Z][\w.]+|[0-9][0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w.]*):(.*)$`

Comment: @anubhava ^ and $ wont work due to where im searching my Regex's.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to give some example inputs and outputs? And what language are you using this from?

Comment: @4castle Doing this in vb.net but it shouldnt be related.

Comment: Is your input string all of those at once? Or is each line a different input string? It seems like @anubhava had the right idea. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ0aS9/1)

Comment: @4castle $ and ^ doesnt seem to work when using StreamReader's ReadAllLines function. Not entirely sure how ReadAllLines is formatted but it seems like its seperated by spaces or something

Comment: If they are separated with newline characters, you can set [multiline mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx) on the regex.

Comment: When I use ^ and $ on lets say email@domain.ext:123 shiny:abc123 it outputs nothing

Comment: @4castle Sweet! That works! Add it as an answe combines with the Regex with ^ and $ and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding anchors `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the regex will force the matches to occur from the beginning to the end of the string.

```
^([a-zA-Z][\w.]+|[0-9][0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w.]*):(.*)$
```

If you then activate the [Multiline mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Multiline), it will make the anchors match at the beginning and end of each **line** instead.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ0aS9/1)